# Support Apple Pencil in my app

Tags: ios, ipad, stylus-pen

I have a colouring app which allows the user to color images, select color and use different colouring techniques.

I need to know is there any requirements I should add to my app to support Apple Pencil input on iPad Pro? Also, is there specific limitations on Apple Pencil input, i.e. some touching functions that it can't be used for?

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations.
Swiping with your Apple Pencil from the top or bottom of the screen does nothing. You'll need to use your finger if you want to access these edge gestures.
The Apple Pencil cannot be used to invoke Slide Over or Split View. Swiping from the right side of the screen gives no response either.

And if you have a second app open in Slide Over, you can't push it off the screen with the Pencil. You also cannot resize apps in Split View with the Pencil.

Comment: these limitations concerns the whole app itself, what about the colouring actions, i.e. swipe to color, select color, erase one and so on?